# How to display data from SQlite to many textview

Tags: textview, android-sqlite, android

i have a problem to display data from sqlite to many textview. Example, for name, i would like to put at the textviewName. below is my code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile);

    TextView TV_Name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVName);
    TextView TV_DOB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVDOB);
    TextView TV_Address = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVAddress);
    TextView TV_BloodType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVBloodType);
    TextView TV_Height =    (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVHeight);
    TextView TV_DrName =    (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVDrName);
    TextView TV_DrContact = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVDrContact);
    TextView TV_CaretakerName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVCaretakerName);
    TextView TV_CaretakerContact = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVCaretakerContact);
    TextView TV_HospitalName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVHospitalName);
    TextView TV_HospitalContact = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVHospitalContact);

    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    String sql = "select * from " + DBHelper.TABLE_PATIENT;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       do {
           idList.add(cursor.getLong(0));
           list.add(cursor.getString(1));
           list.add(cursor.getString(2));
           list.add(cursor.getString(3));
           list.add(cursor.getString(4));
           list.add(cursor.getString(5));
           list.add(cursor.getString(6));
           list.add(cursor.getString(7));
           list.add(cursor.getString(8));
           list.add(cursor.getString(9));
           list.add(cursor.getString(10));
           list.add(cursor.getString(11));
           list.add(cursor.getString(12));
           list.add(cursor.getString(13));

       } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    TV_Name.setText(cursor.getString(1)); 
        TV_DOB.setText(cursor.getString(2));
    cursor.close(); 

}
```

but i'm getting error java.lang.NullPointerException

update:
here my DB

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public static final String DB_NAME = "MyDocDB";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1; 

//Table Patient Details//
    public static final String TABLE_PATIENT = "patient";
    public static final String PATIENT_ID = "id";
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String DOB = "dob";
    public static final String ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String BLOODTYPE = "bloodtype";
    public static final String HEIGHT = "height";
    public static final String DRNAME = "drname";
    public static final String DRCONTACT = "drcontact";
    public static final String GUARDIANNAME1 = "guardianname1";
    public static final String GUARDIANCONTACT1 = "guardiancontact1";
    public static final String GUARDIANNAME2 = "guardianname2";
    public static final String GUARDIANCONTACT2 = "guardiancontact2";
    public static final String HOSPITALNAME = "hospitalname";
    public static final String HOSPITALCONTACT = "hospitalcontact";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    createTable(db);    
            testInsert(db);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}   

//create table
public void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    String query = "create table "+ TABLE_PATIENT +" (" +
            PATIENT_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement," +
            NAME + " text," +
            DOB + " text," +
            ADDRESS + " text," +
            BLOODTYPE + " text," +
            HEIGHT + " text," +
            DRNAME + " text," +
            DRCONTACT + " text," +
            GUARDIANNAME1 + " text," +
            GUARDIANCONTACT1 + " text," +
            GUARDIANNAME2 + " text," +
            GUARDIANCONTACT2 + " text," +
            HOSPITALNAME + " text," +
            HOSPITALCONTACT + " text)";
    db.execSQL(query);  
}


//insert
public void insertDataProfile(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, String dob,
        String address, String bloodtype, String height,
        String drname, String drcontact, String guardianname1, 
        String guardiancontact1, String guardianname2, 
        String guardiancontact2, String hospitalname, String     hospitalcontact)
{
    ContentValues cvPatient = new ContentValues();
    cvPatient.put(NAME, name);
    cvPatient.put(DOB, dob);
    cvPatient.put(ADDRESS, address);
    cvPatient.put(BLOODTYPE, bloodtype);
    cvPatient.put(HEIGHT, height);
    cvPatient.put(DRNAME, drname);
    cvPatient.put(DRCONTACT, drcontact);
    cvPatient.put(GUARDIANNAME1, guardianname1);
    cvPatient.put(GUARDIANCONTACT1, guardiancontact1);
    cvPatient.put(GUARDIANNAME2, guardianname2);
    cvPatient.put(GUARDIANCONTACT2, guardiancontact2);
    cvPatient.put(HOSPITALNAME, hospitalname);
    cvPatient.put(HOSPITALCONTACT, hospitalcontact);
    db.insert(TABLE_PATIENT, null, cvPatient);
}

public void testInsert(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "
    + TABLE_PATIENT
    + "name, dob, address, bloodtype, height, drname, "
    + "drcontact, guardianname1, guardiancontact1, " 
    + "guardianname2, guardiancontact2,hospitalname, "
    + "hospitalcontact"
    + " VALUES ('muna', '11/02/90', 'No 34, Taman Seri Mengkuang 8', " +
    "'0', '158', 'dr nurul', '12344', 'dada', '141'," +
    "'fafa', '34141', 'faga', '14141');");

public Cursor getAllData(SQLiteDatabase db)
{

    return db.query(TABLE_PATIENT, new String[]{PATIENT_ID, NAME, ADDRESS,
            BLOODTYPE, HEIGHT, DRNAME, DRCONTACT, GUARDIANNAME1, GUARDIANCONTACT1,
            GUARDIANNAME2, GUARDIANCONTACT2, HOSPITALNAME, HOSPITALCONTACT},
            null, null, null, null, null);  
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

{

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {   
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.profile);

  TextView TV_Name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVName);
  TextView TV_DOB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVDOB);
  TextView TV_Address = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVAddress);
  TextView TV_BloodType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVBloodType);
  TextView TV_Height =    (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVHeight);
  TextView TV_DrName =    (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVDrName);
  TextView TV_DrContact = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVDrContact);
  TextView TV_CaretakerName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVCaretakerName);
  TextView TV_CaretakerContact = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVCaretakerContact);
  TextView TV_HospitalName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVHospitalName);
  TextView TV_HospitalContact = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVHospitalContact);

DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(this);
database = helper.getWritableDatabase();

String sql = "select * from " + DBHelper.TABLE_PATIENT;
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
       idList.add(cursor.getLong(0));
       list.add(cursor.getString(1));
       list.add(cursor.getString(2));
       list.add(cursor.getString(3));
       list.add(cursor.getString(4));
       list.add(cursor.getString(5));
       list.add(cursor.getString(6));
       list.add(cursor.getString(7));
       list.add(cursor.getString(8));
       list.add(cursor.getString(9));
       list.add(cursor.getString(10));
       list.add(cursor.getString(11));
       list.add(cursor.getString(12));
       list.add(cursor.getString(13));

   } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

cursor.moveToFirst();
TV_Name.setText(cursor.getString(1)); 
TV_DOB.setText(cursor.getString(2));
cursor.close();
```

}

did you try this?

Comment: Check if your cursor has a value in the start. put an if-block this way--- 
'if(!cursor.MovetoFirst()){
      Log.i("user2089567","My cursor has no value")
      return;
}'
Tell me what this returns?

Comment: ya, it reply my cursor has no value

Comment: yeah its probably that then

Comment: listen if you are using eclipse you can pull your database out of the android virtual device and see whats happening. I think it is safe to assume the error is happening in your database. Is the testInsert() working?

Comment: So, the database is being created but you are not able to insert into it?

Comment: done already with insert data.. i checked back my table no data.. thats why cursor prob.. now i want to try back to view in textview.. will get back to you

Comment: i got it, before this my db is prob.. now i fix already.. the code is still same.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that because you have already moved your cursor to the end using moveToNext? Call MoveToFirst before accessing data again I think.

Comment: not work.. plz, i've stuck here for a while just to display the data